# wireframe with shared vertices

Tags: webgl, shader

I am trying to implement a wireframe shader based on [barycentric coordinates](http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/02/easy-wireframe-display-with-barycentric-coordinates/)

Unless I missed some important point, this works fine as long as all vertices are never shared (all triangles have unique vertices), but the moment any sharing happens the techniques fails on me. There is always a condition where two vertices with the same barycentric but from different triangles are used to form a new triangle and causes artifacts.

Is single-pass wireframe rendering possible with shared vertices ?